# Часть окружности или область, ограниченная прямой и кривой?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Мне нужно с помощью OpenGL на Java (библиотека JOGL) нарисовать вот такую фигуру:

[image]

Известен `x`. "Портить" область под этой фигурой нельзя. Я вообще не знаю OpenGL, ради каждого шага смотрю туториал или гуглю. Но вот это не могу найти. Мне даже непонятно, надо это рассматривать как часть окружности (это ж не сектор, а как оно тогда называется?) или как область, ограниченную прямой и кривой.

P.S. Если вы знаете ответ на Objective Pascal или C++, пишите тоже. Там все методы одинаковые, просто обернуты в Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Рисование эллипсов - известная проблема для 3d графики.*

В общем случае сэмулировать эллипс можно некоторым набором треугольников, сложенных в соответствующий `strip`. Например, разместить вершины на сторонах *по синусу и косинусу соответственно.*

В вашем случае, предполагаю, что имеет смысл взять текстуру с альфа каналом и отрисовать ее на полотне из четырех вершин `(0,0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)`. При этом, если сделать текстуру достаточно большой и включить соответствующий `texture sampling`, *то артефактов при сжатии не будет, и все будет выглядеть достаточно хорошо.*

Comment: А мне в одной части этого курсовика надо, чтобы такой полукруг был еще и объемный. Ну т.е. типа часть цилиндра. Это же совсем сложно получается?

Вот еще ответ на эту же тему: [OpenGL—ES 1.0 2d rounded rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369507/opengles-1-0-2d-rounded-rectangle)